# Unity: how to animate between tab icons?

Tags: user-interface, animation, mobile, unity-game-engine

alright, I'm not that well versed in UI elements but I need to make 3 icons that one can tap to move between tabs, but I need the color of the image to move with/in the direction of the new tapped icon. As depicted below, the selected icon would be filled white:

[image]

Then when selected 2nd one:

[image]

I know how to do this, but what I cant seem to create is animating the switch between them where the white background appears to move "behind" the icons into the next one. I couldn't find any examples but like this:

[image]

How can I do this? In my project I won't just have squares but actual icons. Are there any icons like this on asset store?

Comment: Take a look at UI Masks maybe : https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-mask - You will have to "empty" the first icon while "filling up" the second one when switching buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Filled` image type for your button images:

[image]

E.g. Add an animator to your canvas (UI Root). Add multiple states to the animator and create one animation for each of them. In each animation change `FillAmount` of the desired images.

These filled images should exist just before the border image in the hierarchy in order to fall behind them.

Also you can skip the animator/animation part and do it in code through a coroutine or simply in Update method.

In order to fill upside an image just change `Fill Origin` to `Top`

Comment: Awesome. Took some coding along with animation but works perfectly. Good solution!